# Structuring backend (REST API) into microservices with Kubernetes (or serverless)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, serverless

I'd like to design my next project in a microservices-based architecture rather than as a monolith. Are microservices generally defined as a set of endpoints that compromise a service (i.e. common dependencies, functionality, etc.) or would each endpoint be its own service?

I've used [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/) before, which defines each endpoint with its dependencies and packages it into a Lambda/FaaS. In Kubernetes is this analogous to each endpoint living in its own pod?

I'm having some trouble thinking about the ideal way to design a new project from the ground up that can make use of autoscaling, microservices, and pay-for-usage, and haven't found much information around it.

Any thoughts/resources on this subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to start from [scaling](https://dzone.com/articles/kubernetes-autoscaling-explained) perspective. Separate apps that should be scaled from apps that shouldn't. That would be [Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/).

Define the connection between apps taking into account fault tolerance and load balancing. Define the autodiscovery strategy. That's what [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) is used for.

Think about how you expose your apps to the outside world. That's what [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) is for.

Think about how you restart and update your apps. That's what [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) do.

Think about cluster security. This is where [Network policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) come to play. Project Calico provides more flexible [solution](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/reference/calicoctl/resources/networkpolicy).

Think about the availability of the whole cluster. Here come the [Kubernetes HA clusters](https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-high-availability-no-single-point-of-failure/)

In special cases you may need to use [DaemonSets](https://hackernoon.com/kubernetes-101-daemonsets-5-c5bbfcbb1579), [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/), [CronJobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) and [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).

If you decide to go deeper, check out other articles in the [Kubernetes concepts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/) section of the official site.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am more wondering at an architectural level how I would define what defines the "app" i.e. what lives in each pod? Is it one endpoint? Lots of endpoints? I'm having trouble on how to architect the "services".

Comment: Here is a good article about Architecting Applications for Kubernetes: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/architecting-applications-for-kubernetes  and several books about Microservices architecture: https://dzone.com/articles/7-microservices-architecture-books-every-devops-en